# Searching online English dictionaries

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, python-3.x

I do always search online English dictionaries for words that I know but want to get a better understanding of and/or to know their other meanings, or for words that I do not know at all. Therefore, I have written a simple program to help me search for English words faster and easier.

Here is my code:

```
import webbrowser

class OnlineDictionary:
    """Represents an online dictionary.

    Attributes:
      name: str
      url: str
    """
    def __init__(self, name, url, sep):
        """Initializes an OnlineDictionary object.

        name: str
        url: str
        sep: str
        """
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
        self.sep = sep

    def search(self, query):
        """Searches the dictionary for a given query.

        url: str
        query: str
        """
        query = self.sep.join(query.split())
        webbrowser.open(self.url + query)


def print_instructions(message, instructions, names, num_of_dics):
    """Prints the available dictionaries, their corresponding
    numerals and the instructions.

    message: str
    instructions: str
    names: list
    num_of_dics: int
    """    
    print(message)

    for numeral, name in zip(range(num_of_dics), names):
        print(numeral, name)

    print()
    print(instructions)     


def get_user_data(num_of_dics):
    """Asks the user for which dictionary 
    to use and for what to search for.

    num_of_dics: int

    Returns: tuple
    """
    while True:
        to_use = input('Specify which dictionary or dictionaries to use.\n')
        if to_use == '*':
            break

        try:
            to_use = to_use.replace(' ', '').split(',')
            numerals = []

            for num in to_use:
                num = int(num)
                if num not in range(num_of_dics):
                    raise
                numerals.append(num)

            to_use = set(numerals)  #set is used to get rid of any duplicates
            break

        except:
            continue

    query = input('Type something to search for.\n')

    return (to_use, query)


def __main__():  
    names = ('Merriam-Webster Dictionary', 'Oxford Dictionary', 'Camberidge Dictionary', 'Collins Dictionary',
             'Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English','The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language')

    urls = ('https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/', 'https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/',
            'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/',
            'https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/', 'https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=')

    seps = ('%20', '_', '-', '-', '-', '%20')  #seperators are used if there are spaces in the query 

    collection = list(zip(names, urls, seps))

    num_of_dics = len(names)

    message = "These are the available dictionaries:\n"

    instructions = """To use a dictionary type its corresponding numeral.
To use more than one dictionary seperate the numerals with ",".
To use all of them type "*". Do not type the quotation marks.\n"""

    print_instructions(message, instructions, names, num_of_dics)

    while True:        
        to_use, query = get_user_data(num_of_dics)
        print()
        dics_to_use = collection if to_use == '*' else [collection[num] for num in to_use]
        dics = [OnlineDictionary(name, url, sep) for name, url, sep in dics_to_use]

        for dic in dics:
            print('Searching %s for "%s"...' % (dic.name, query))
            dic.search(query)

        print('Finished searching. Check your Web browser.\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    __main__()
```

I would appreciate any suggestions and comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks pretty good. I have a few suggestions though:

1. There should be a way to exit (maybe if you don't type anything when it asks which dictionaries?)
2. You should probably use `urllib.parse.urljoin` instead of `+`.
3. <s>You should probably use recursion instead of using `while True` then always `break`ing or `continue`ing.</s>
4. You don't need parentheses when returning tuples.
5. Bare `raise` statements are for *re*raising exceptions. Otherwise, it gives you `RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise`.
6. Don't use bare `except`.
7. I would probably use a list of tuples instead of using `zip`.
8. You could pass around the whole list instead of its length.
9. You can use `enumerate(iterable)` instead of `zip(range(len(iterable)), iterable)`. What `enumerate` does is create an iterable that when iterated, yields tuples of increasing numbers starting with 0 and the next item from the iterable (in your case a list) you are enumerating. More info [at the Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).
10. You should handle the logic for `*` in one place.
11. Contained the logic for handling numerals within the `get_user_data` function.
12. You should probably name your main function `main` instead of `__main__`.
13. Don't combine multiline strings and `'\n'`.
14. It might be good to have it display the result directly in the console instead of the web browser, but that would be a whole other project.
15. You should probably return directly instead of using `break`.
16. I might have made a few other minor changes.

Note that some of the changes are just personal preferences.

The result (also available at https://repl.it/@solly_ucko/DictionarySearchCodeReview):

```
import webbrowser
from urllib.parse import urljoin

class OnlineDictionary:
    """Represents an online dictionary.

    Attributes:
name: str
url: str
    """
    def __init__(self, name, url, sep):
        """Initializes an OnlineDictionary object.

        name: str
        url: str
        sep: str
        """
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
        self.sep = sep

    def search(self, query):
        """Searches the dictionary for a given query.

        url: str
        query: str
        """
        query = self.sep.join(query.split())
        webbrowser.open(urljoin(self.url, query))


def print_instructions(message, instructions, dictionaries):
    """Prints the available dictionaries, their corresponding
    numerals and the instructions.

    message: str
    instructions: str
    names: list
    num_of_dics: int
    """    
    print(message)

    for numeral, (name, _, _) in enumerate(dictionaries):
        print(numeral, name)

    print()
    print(instructions)     


def get_user_data(dictionaries):
    """Asks the user for which dictionary 
    to use and for what to search for.

    num_of_dics: int

    Returns: tuple
    """

    while True:
        to_use = input('Specify which dictionary or dictionaries to use.\n')

        if to_use == '':
            return (), ''
        elif to_use == '*':
            to_use = dictionaries
        else:
            try:
                to_use = to_use.replace(' ', '').split(',')
                numerals = []

                for num in to_use:
                    num = int(num)

                    if num not in range(len(dictionaries)):
                        raise ValueError

                    numerals.append(num)

                to_use = set(map(dictionaries.__getitem__, numerals)) # set is used to get rid of duplicates
                query = input('Type something to search for.\n')
                return to_use, query
            except ValueError:
                continue


def main():
    dictionaries = [
        ('Merriam-Webster Dictionary', 'https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/', '%20'),
        ('Oxford Dictionary', 'https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/', '_'),
        ('Camberidge Dictionary', 'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/', '-'),
        ('Collins Dictionary', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/', '-'),
        ('Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English', 'https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/', '-'),
        ('The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language', 'https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=', '%20')
    ]

    message = 'These are the available dictionaries:\n'

    instructions = """To use a dictionary type its corresponding numeral.
To use more than one dictionary separate the numerals with ",".
To use all of them type "*". Do not type the quotation marks.
"""

    print_instructions(message, instructions, dictionaries)

    while True:        
        to_use, query = get_user_data(dictionaries)

        if not to_use or not query:
            break

        print()
        chosen_dictionaries = [OnlineDictionary(name, url, sep) for name, url, sep in to_use]

        for dictionary in chosen_dictionaries:
            print('Searching %s for "%s"...' % (dictionary.name, query))
            dictionary.search(query)

        print('Finished searching. Check your Web browser.\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and great review, Solomon! I am a beginner and would like to get a better understanding of the changes that you made, so could you please elaborate on the changes that are not personal preferences, and that help make the code better?

Comment: @MahmudMuhammadNaguib, I think the main things that I called personal preferences were #2, 4, 7, 12, and 13. As for the others, do you have any specific questions, or should I try to elaborate in general?

Comment: Thanks! Things are clearer now. I am now refactoring the code according to your answer. It would be nice if you elaborate on using `enumerate(iterable)` instead of `zip(len(iterable), iterable)`.

Comment: @MahmudMuhammadNaguib Elaborated in the answer: What `enumerate` does is create an iterable that when iterated, yields tuples of increasing numbers starting with 0 and the next item from the iterable (in your case a list) you are enumerating. More info [at the Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: Thanks again, Solomon! I have finished refactoring the code. The code is better now thanks to your review. Making `get_user_data` return the chosen dictionary/dictionaries directly instead of returning the symbol/symbols that represent them has enhanced the code's reusability a lot.

Comment: @MahmudMuhammadNaguib Great! Happy to help.

Comment: I came back to this and realized that I actually disagree with #3. I'd recommend returning directly instead of breaking, though.

Comment: Nice to hear from you again, Solomon! Can you elaborate on that, please? I have refactored the code and posted a follow-up question which you can find here (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201328/searching-online-english-dictionaries-follow-up), in case you are interested.